# what is wrong with my invert tree function?

Tags: python, data-structures, tree

i am trying to invert a binary tree, but when i print, nothing changes.
my strategy is to the nextSibling a prevSibling. that means, i need to reverse the linked-list, but here i am just using nodes, not linked-lists. please help

```
class treeNode:

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None
        self.nextSibling = None
        self.level = 0
        self.prevSibling = None

    def add_children(self,*child):
        for i in child:
            i.parent = self
            self.children.append(i)
            if len(self.children) > 1:
                self.children[-2].nextSibling = i
                i.prevSibling = self.children[-2]

class Tree:

    def __init__(self,root:treeNode):
        self.root = root
        self.depth = 0
    def invert_tree(self):
        self.root.children = self.root.children[::-1]
        kid = self.root.children[0]
        while kid != self.root:
            if len(kid.children) == 0:
                while kid.parent:
                    if kid.prevSibling:
                        kid = kid.prevSibling
                        break
                    else:
                        kid = kid.parent
            else:
                kid.children = kid.children[::-1]
                kid = kid.children[0]
parent = treeNode(1)
child = treeNode(2)
grand = treeNode(3)
parent.add_children(child,treeNode(22))
child.add_children(grand,treeNode(33))
grand.add_children(treeNode(4))
tree = Tree(parent)
tree.print_tree()
tree.invert_tree()
```

this is the output i get:

```
1
|__ 22
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is inverting a binary tree?

Comment: to invert a binary tree is to reverse the order of the nodes.

Comment: Why does you tree structure keep the children both as a doubly-linked list (using `prevSibling` and `nextSibling`) and as a standard list (`children`)? You should stick to one such structure only. Note that your code does not alter the linked list version in any way. Secondly, your code calls `print_tree`, but you didn't share the code.

Comment: Generally speaking, questions seeking debugging help are off-topic here. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: No reply to my comment?